# How can I parse nodes and edges information from XML file

Tags: matlab, xml-parsing

I am new in xml file in matlab. I want to read a xml file (network) with nodes and edges, in order to get the following info:

1. The **node** id, label, Human Readable Label, uniprot values
2. The **edge** id, label, source, target

Here is the xml file:

```
</node>
<node id="1696" label="Q13418">
    <att name="shared name" value="Q13418" type="string"/>
    <att name="name" value="Q13418" type="string"/>
    <att name="selected" value="0" type="boolean"/>
    <att name="Taxonomy ID" value="9606" type="string"/>
    <att name="Taxonomy Name" value="human" type="string"/>
    <att name="Human Readable Label" value="ILK" type="string"/>
    <att name="uniprotkb_accession" value="Q13418" type="string"/>
    <att name="uniprot" type="list">
        <att name="uniprot" value="Q68DZ3" type="string"/>
        <att name="uniprot" value="B7Z1I0" type="string"/>
        <att name="uniprot" value="ILK-1" type="string"/>
        <att name="uniprot" value="ILK-2" type="string"/>
        <att name="uniprot" value="B7Z418" type="string"/>
        <att name="uniprot" value="ILK2" type="string"/>
        <att name="uniprot" value="ILK" type="string"/>
        <att name="uniprot" value="Q13418" type="string"/>
        <att name="uniprot" value="ILK1" type="string"/>
        <att name="uniprot" value="59 kDa serine/threonine-protein kinase"          type="string"/>
        <att name="uniprot" value="D3DQU0" type="string"/>
        <att name="uniprot" value="p59ILK" type="string"/>
        <att name="uniprot" value="P57043" type="string"/>
    </att>
    <att name="psi-mi" type="list">
        --------
        --------
        --------
</node>


</edge>
<edge id="1695" label="Q9NVD7 (EBI-6690276) P48059" source="1689" target="1694" cy:directed="1">
    <att name="shared name" value="Q9NVD7 (EBI-6690276) P48059" type="string"/>
    <att name="shared interaction" value="EBI-6690276" type="string"/>
    <att name="name" value="Q9NVD7 (EBI-6690276) P48059" type="string"/>
    <att name="selected" value="0" type="boolean"/>
    <att name="interaction" value="EBI-6690276" type="string"/>
    <att name="Author" type="list">
        <att name="Author" value="Zhang et al. (2002)" type="string"/>
    </att>
    <att name="Primary Interaction Type" value="association" type="string"/>
    <att name="Interaction Type" type="list">
        <att name="Interaction Type" value="association" type="string"/>
    </att>
    -----------
    -----------
    </graphics>
</edge>
```

I used `xml-read` function to read the file.

Unfortunately I got the information like this:
[image]

Any help will be highly appreciate

Comment: I tried to reconstruct a valid xml from your example, but I failed to do so. Please try to create an example which is [valid xml](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Comment: I tried to upload the file. but I got Error each time!!!

Comment: Sorry! This document cannot be checked

Comment: Not sure what went wrong there. Maybe you can upload your full xml somewhere? Your shortened example is broken, but the original seems to be okay because `xmlread` returned something.

Comment: Dear Daniel..I am almost sort the problem. I  need some help in this section   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35480749/parsing-information-between-two-tags-in-matlab

Comment: Please delete this question as it is no longer needed. I will take a look at the new question.